# Need some help understanding Apache-camel bindy

Tags: java, csv, marshalling, apache-camel

At this moment I have a `JTable` I want to export to a `.csv` file.
I've had another question put on this site, but this one is specific to my `Bindy` problem.

With bindy it is possible to annotate all the classes and datafields you want to marshall or unmarshall. The problem is after the annotating I have no idea how to set up my app to create the CSV for me.

I've found explanations (partly), and examples (that didn't help me find out how it works).
`http://camel.apache.org/csv.html`

Especially with above link I had problems understanding this part below:
An example: if you send a message with this map...

```
Map<String, Object> body = new HashMap<String, Object>();
body.put("foo", "abc");
body.put("bar", 123);
```

... through this route ...

```
from("direct:start").
marshal().csv().
to("mock:result");
```

... you will end up with a String containing this CSV message

```
abc,123
```

`http://camel.apache.org/bindy.html`

Could anyone help me explain how this works, because I cannot seem to get the grasp of it.

Answer (score 0):

The example you refer to on http://camel.apache.org/csv.html shows how to marshal one row of data to csv, being two columns named foo and bar with respective values abc and 123.

**foo  bar**

abc  123

Since the headers are not output (in this example) you end up with

```
abc,123
```

If you want to output multiple rows of data, refer to the "Marshalling a List to CSV" heading on the same page:

> If you have multiple rows of data you want to be marshalled into CSV
>   format you can now store the message payload as a List> object where the list contains a Map for each row.